# Display image description as tooltip

Tags: feature-request, images

Could a tooltip with the image description

`![enter image description here][1]`

be displayed when hovering over an image?
This would make additional use, next to the one for [visually impaired](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8356/19341)...

Comment: ... and don't forget [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/435/)...

Comment: Does this mean I need to go back and fill in all the image descriptions that I've neglected in the past? Ouch!

Comment: @robjohn let's have it optional.

Comment: Perhaps we should display it if the description is anything but blanks (standard) or "enter image description here" (for slackers like me).

Comment: @robjohn sounds great...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add hover text in parentheses:

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/..... (hover text)
```

or in quotation marks:

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/..... "hover text"
```

Like this:

[image: Display image description as tooltip]

[Works for links, too](http://math.stackexchange.com).

There's a good reason to have alt-text and hover-text as separate attributes: one is intended for users who don't see the image, the other for those who do.

Comment: thank you so much...

Comment: Can it be made to work for segments of text? Like, if "ZFC" is typed in an answer and you want a tooltip that reads "Zermelo-Frankel with axiom of choice"? Failing that, can you have a link that goes nowhere?